# Constraint error with greater than operator

Tags: constraints, cplex

I'm ever in trouble with Cplex, I don't know why.
So I attach a snippet of code:

```
 dvar int+ soglia[pazienti][giorni][slot];
 dvar int+ sogliar[pazienti][giorni][slot];
 dvar int+ soglial[pazienti][giorni][slot];

 forall(k in giornidue, w in slot)  sum(j in pazienti)(soglia[j,k,w]+sogliar[j,k,w]+soglial[j,k,w]) > sum(j in pazienti)(soglia[j,k-1,w]+sogliar[j,k-1,w]+soglial[j,k-1,w]);
```

And get this error:

```
Function operator >(dexpr int, dexpr int) not available in CPLEX context
```

I don't understand why i can not use > between int.

Comment: You can't use strict inequalities in linear programming and related variants like MILP. That is because the constraints define the space of possible solutions and must include the points on its boundary edges and surfaces in the set of feasible solutions. Check in almost any basic text on LP and MILP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments to your answer, strict inequality is not supported in the theory of linear programming. However, since you know that both sides of your expression are integer,

```
a > b
```

is equivalent to

```
a >= b + 1
```

where the latter does not require strict inequality. Rewriting the constraint like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's comment is actually a perfectly valid answer: "You can't use strict inequalities in linear programming and related variants like MILP. That is because the constraints define the space of possible solutions and must include the points on its boundary edges and surfaces in the set of feasible solutions. Check in almost any basic text on LP and MILP."

Comment: Yeah, I don't why I did not think to this.

Answer (score 0):

With whatever modeling API of CPLEX, you will not be able to do strict inequalities between variables.

You should use ˋ<=ˋ

the following would eliminate this error

```
 range pazienti = 1..10;
 range giorni = 1..10;
 range giornidue = 2..10;
 range slot = 1..10;

 dvar int+ soglia[pazienti][giorni][slot];
 dvar int+ sogliar[pazienti][giorni][slot];
 dvar int+ soglial[pazienti][giorni][slot];

 subject to {
   forall (k in giornidue, w in slot)  
      sum(j in pazienti)(soglia[j,k,w]+sogliar[j,k,w]+soglial[j,k,w]) >=
     sum(j in pazienti)(soglia[j,k-1,w]+sogliar[j,k-1,w]+soglial[j,k-1,w]);
 }
```